# Creating jpa entity with self reference

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have pojo that needs to self reference with a one to one mapping. I'm using flyway to bring up the tables. The app launches fine, however when I try to to do a get request I get the following error:

```
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle
```

I think there's something wrong with the way I'm self referencing. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my sql:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_person (
    id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    parent_id BIGINT(20),
    primary key (id));
    
CREATE SEQUENCE person_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Here is my model:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="tbl_person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "person_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="person_seq",allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name="id",insertable =false,nullable = false,updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;


    @Column(name="address")
    private String address
   
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Person person;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is from jackson. So it fails on the conversion to a java object or back to json/xml not on writing it to your database.

The problem is that the resulting JSON object could contain another Person-json which could refer to the same person. This would create a infinite loop.

In this would result in sth like that:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Example",
    "address": "example-address",
    "person": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Example",
        "address": "example-address",
        "person": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Example",
            "address": "example-address",
            "person": {
               ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: You could map the "person" attribute with the id of the person instead of the whole person object:
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-identity-reference.html

Comment: Can you give me an example of how can I do it in my code?

Comment: It's more or less exactly the same like explained on the page:
Add @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id") to your class and @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true) to the "person"-property. 
There's an example on the website I sent you.
And maybe remove the @JsonManagedReference

Comment: I've added the required annotations. Still getting the same error

Comment: Try adding the @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true) to your Person class instead of the property